# How to set the same y-axis on a graph with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I am trying to plot a set of data points on the same axis showing the minor differences in their data. When I go to plot the lines, the y-axis is stacked with almost repeating data points instead of mixing the data points. I am limited to using numpy, math, and matplotlib.pyplot.

I apologize in advance if there is a better way to upload graphs.

I am able to get one graph with two lines as desired, but it resets the y-axis for each plot (stacks it). I have tried setting the `plt.ylim(0,1000)`, putting both (x,y) couples in the same plot line amongst other things.

[My wrong graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee3sd.jpg)

[Correct y-axis graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF1UD.jpg)

I used these imports:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Here is the code I have been using:

```
    getKey = [m for m in data] 
    
    #get reversed list for ideal values
    ideal2 = (data[getKey[0]])
    ideal2r = []
    for k in ideal2:
        ideal2r.insert(0,k)

    #get reversed list for actual values
    actual2 = (data[getKey[1]])
    actual2r = []
    for k in actual2:
        actual2r.insert(0,k)

    #get reversed list for measured values
    measured2 = (data[getKey[2]])
    measured2r = []
    for k in measured2:
        measured2r.insert(0,k)

    #plot the first graph comparing ideal to actual values over increments 0-30(incs)
    plt.plot(incs,ideal2r,'b', label = 'ideal')
    plt.plot(incs,actual2r,'r', label = 'actual')
    #plt.axis('equal')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

    #plot the second graph comparing actual to measured values over increments 0-30(incs)
    plt.plot(incs,actual2r,'b', label = 'actual')
    plt.plot(incs,measured2r,'r', label = 'measured')
    #plt.axis('equal')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

When I use this method in a different function it prints on the same y-axis for each line (0,1000)

[Other function graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C60dE.jpg)

other method:

```
    k = np.linspace(0,9,10)
    x = [1000, 750, 563, 422, 316, 237, 178, 133, 100, 75]
    z = [927,870,567,271,132,47,92,79,99,123]

    # Complete the rest of the function below this line

    r = 200
    a = 0.75 
    x_est = [z[0]]
    p_est = [1]
    g_est = [0]
    x_hat = z[0]
    p = 1 #cant be 0 

    for i in range(len(k)-1):
        #initialization 
        x_hat = a*x_hat
        p = a*p*a 

        #predict
        g = p/(p+r) # adding noise prediction 
        x_hat = x_hat + g*(z[i] - x_hat)
        p = (1-g)*p 

        #update
        p_est.append(p)
        x_est.append(x_hat)
        g_est.append(g)

    plt.plot(k,x,'b', label = 'true state') 
    plt.plot(k,z,'r', label = 'observation')
    plt.plot(k, x_est, 'g', label = 'estimate')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

[The data i have been using is contained here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1X7TZ.jpg)

Comment: What's ```actual2.dtype```?

Comment: It is a list as well as actual2r. The dictionary this pulls from has four keys each with a list as the values. I thought about merging the list but from what I understand I would only be able to plot one line with twenty data points instead of two lines each with ten points. @fdireito

Comment: And the list elements are numbers (such as floats) or strings? For instance, whats the output of ```type(actual2[0])```?

Comment: they were all `numpy.str_` and the working function had them as `numpy.float64` so I was able to convert them to a `numpy.float64` in the flawed function and it seems to be working properly! Thank you @fdireito I'll be sure to check the type more frequently when troubleshooting future issues!